# BCP multiple files in/out using Azure Active Directory Interactive

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to **export/import tables using bcp**, I am able to do it one by one as the documentation says **using Azure Active Directory Interactive** (I require Multifactor authentication to access the DB), by this method, it prompts an external window to set my credentials, so I should do this action for all the "IN" and "OUT" for all the tables (more than 20 and can increase in the future). **Is there any way to avoid re-enter my credentials and execute export and import in one shot?**

Example of BCP script:

```
bcp bcptest out "c:\last\data1.dat" -c -t -S aadserver.database.windows.net -d testdb -G -U alice@aadtest.onmicrosoft.com
```

Note: I know that script can be created by query, but again, **my issue is to re-enter credentials for each file**.

```
select 'bcp dbo.' + st.name + ' out c:\' + st.name + '.dat -c -t -S ' + 'aadserver.database.windows.net -d '  +    DB_NAME()   + ' -G -U alice@aadtest.onmicrosoft.com' from sys.tables st
 
select 'bcp dbo.' + st.name + ' in c:\' + st.name + '.dat -c -t -S ' + 'aadserver.database.windows.net -d '  +   'newdb'    + ' -G -U v-alice@aadtest.onmicrosoft.com' from sys.tables st
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, **I was not able to do it via Azure Active Directory Interactive**, **I had to ask for the user and password credentials**, which allows me full access, so I created the next Power Shell script:

```
#Source DB params
$dbServerSource = "serversource.database.windows.net"
$dbDatabaseSource = "dbsource"
$dbUserSource = "Data Base User"
$dbPasswordSource = "'password  - do not remove the quotes'"
#Target DB params [example params]
$dbServerTarget = "newServer.database.windows.net"
$dbDatabaseTarget = "NewDB"
$dbUserTarget = "NewUser"
$dbPasswordTarget = "'password - do not remove the quotes'"


#SQL Connection - connection to SQL server
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $dbServerSource; Database = $dbDatabaseSource; User ID = $dbUserSource; Password = $dbPasswordSource;"
$SqlConnection.Open()

#SQL Command - set up the SQL call
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "select  st.name  from sys.tables st where st.name not in('sysdiagrams');"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

#SQL Adapter - get the results using the SQL Command
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
#Close SQL Connection
$sqlConnection.Close();


foreach ($Row in $DataSet.Tables[0].Rows) { 
   $table = "$($Row[0])" 
   write-Output "--------------Crteate templates " + $table + "---------------"
   $psCommand = 'bcp dbo.' + $table + ' format nul -c -x -f ' + $table + '.xml  -S ' + $dbServerSource  + " -d " + $dbDatabaseSource + " -U " + $dbUserSource +  " -P " + $dbPasswordSource
   Invoke-Expression $psCommand
   write-Output "--------------Extract Data " + $table + "---------------"
   $psCommand = 'bcp dbo.' + $table + ' out ' + $table + '.dat -E -f ' + $table + '.xml -e ' + $table + 'out_logout.log -S ' + $dbServerSource  + " -d " + $dbDatabaseSource + " -U " + $dbUserSource +  " -P " + $dbPasswordSource
   Invoke-Expression $psCommand
   write-Output "--------------Import Data " + $table + "---------------"
   $psCommand = 'bcp dbo.' + $table + ' in ' + $table + '.dat -E  -f ' + $table + '.xml -e ' + $table + 'in_logout.log -S '  + $dbServerTarget  + " -d " + $dbDatabaseTarget + " -U " + $dbUserTarget +  " -P " + $dbPasswordTarget
   Invoke-Expression $psCommand
}
```

This script does the next steps:

- Connect to the source DB
- Get the tables (you can exclude or include tables in the select)
- Execute bcp commands for each table:

  - Get source templates
  - Get source data
  - Migrate source data to target